# How do I get the last 24hours in 24 rows from now?

Tags: mysql

For example my datetime is 2019/29/08 16:47

My table looks like this

```
ID     stuff    timestamp
1      ...      2019/29/08 16:47
2      ...      2019/29/08 16:45
3      ...      ...
50     ...      2019/29/08 15:47
...    ...      ...
100    ...      2019/29/08 14:47
```

How do I select only the rows, that are 1h, 2h, 3h, .. ,24h before now?

to get something like

```
ID    stuff    timestamp
1     ...      2019/29/08 15:47
2     ...      2019/29/08 14:47
3     ...      2019/29/08 13:47
..    ...      ...
24   ...       2019/28/08 16:47
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. `Y/m/d h:i` isn't a data type with which I'm familiar, and elipsis are rarely enlightening. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: actually format is yyyy/dd/mm

Comment: What data type is timestamp column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE timestamp IN ( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 5 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 7 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 9 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 10 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 11 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 13 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 14 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 15 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 16 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 17 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 19 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 20 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 21 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 22 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 23 HOUR, 
                     NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: I mean it's none of my business, but why do you do it? Why?